# Give an individual cron task for each Feeds import

Tags: feeds

Can I separate different import tasks? I have feeds module installed and it runs multiple import jobs per cron. So I would like to at least order them (give different weights to them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was to suggest [Elysia Cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron), but it [sounds like Feeds doesn't yet support individual per feed cron jobs](https://drupal.org/node/1345976#comment-5317198).

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you might consider the [Feed Import](https://drupal.org/project/feed_import) module, which can apparently be made to [support per feed cron jobs via Elysia Cron](https://drupal.org/node/1534960#comment-5883648).

Comment: Thanks I decided to not use feeds at all - it's too heavy and does not so much. So I wrote my own module that works just fine

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use Elysia and define a cron job for each of the feed imports like this:

```
/*
 * Feed import managed by Elysia
 */
function MYMODULE_cronapi($op, $job = NULL) {
  $items['fetch_MYFEED_cron'] = array(
    'description' => 'Fetch MYFEED',
    'rule' => '*/10 * * * *', // Every 10 minutes
    'callback' => 'MYMODULE_fetch_MYFEED_cron',
    'arguments' => array(array('MYFEED')),
  );
  return $items;
}
function MYMODULE_fetch_MYFEED_cron($feednames){
  if (function_exists('feeds_source')){
    foreach($feednames as $feedname){
      $source = feeds_source($feedname);
      $source->import();
    }
  }
}
```